# Disable power saving mode for WebView on Android 9

Tags: samsung, battery-life, chrome-for-android, webview, doze-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active2 (SM-T390) tablet with `Android 9` and `One UI 1.1` and the latest available updates. An app with an `WebView` looses connection after about six minutes of standby. I tried to disable enrgy saving for the app as well as `Chrome` and `Android System WebView` (Chrome and WebView disables each other). This approach does work for another Samsung device with Android 10, but not on Android 9.

Is there another app, which I have to exclude from power saving? Or is this a bug in Android or from Samsung?

Comment: Are you on Wifi or mobile data?

Comment: I'm on Wifi. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Then most likely the connection is closed because your device shuts down Wifi.

Comment: Can I do something against it except never turn the screen off?